# Edit Xaml files on debuging Visual studio 2019, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to Edit UI XAML files with my program running and see these changes without to stop my program...

When I change these files right now It just o nothing until I close my program and start again.

For exmaple: 
 this is my xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

http://prntscr.com/nwiw0o

I see an empty white screen

When I change it (on debug) to

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Background="Blue">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

http://prntscr.com/nwiw7q

Nothing is change

But when I restart my program 
It runs this blue screen... 
http://prntscr.com/nwiwiw

I think its something about debugging option? 
this is my page open list

http://prntscr.com/nwiwtu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have "Edit and continue" enabled, because you can just edit xaml and see the result immediately if you do.

From the Debug menu, choose Options.
On the left Debugging should be selected for you and the default will be the first option - General. If that isn't selected, do so.

Scroll the right panel down.

Tick the Enable UI debugging tools for XAML and at least Enable XAML Edit and Continue.

[image]

You should then be able to change simple properties in XAML and see your changes reflected immediately in the running UI.  It does not work for everything though.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/ui-development-made-easier-with-xaml-edit-continue/